# How do you turn off (or hide) the seconds y axis scale on a combination chart in openpyxl?

Tags: python, openpyxl

How do you turn off (or hide) the seconds y axis scale on a combination chart in openpyxl?

I can find the xml difference by comparing the before and after changes to hide the scale (I just change the excel file extension to '.zip' to access the xml):

```
    -<c:valAx>
<c:axId val="156672520"/>
-<c:scaling>
<c:orientation val="minMax"/>
</c:scaling>
<c:delete val="0"/>
<c:axPos val="r"/>
<c:majorGridlines/>
<c:numFmt sourceLinked="1" formatCode="0.0"/>
<c:majorTickMark val="out"/>
<c:minorTickMark val="none"/>
<c:tickLblPos val="none"/>     # this changes from 'nextTo'
<c:crossAx val="207247000"/>
<c:crosses val="max"/>
<c:crossBetween val="between"/>
</c:valAx>
```

I've tried this (last few lines are the 'tickLblPos' ):

```
    mainchart = LineChart()
mainchart.style = 12
v2 = Reference(WorkSheetOne, min_col=1, min_row=2+CombBarLineDataOffsetFromTop, max_row=3+CombBarLineDataOffsetFromTop, max_col=13)
mainchart.add_data(v2, titles_from_data=True, from_rows=True)

mainchart.layout = Layout(
    ManualLayout(
    x=0.12, y=0.25, # position from the top
    h=0.9, w=0.75, # this is scaling the chart into the container
    xMode="edge",
    yMode="edge",
    )
)

mainchart.title = "Chart Title"

# Style the lines
s1 = mainchart.series[0]
#Marker type
s1.marker.symbol = "diamond" # triangle
s1.marker.size = 9
s1.marker.graphicalProperties.solidFill = "C00000" # Marker filling
s1.marker.graphicalProperties.line.solidFill = "000000" # Marker outline
s1.graphicalProperties.line.noFill = False
# Line color
s1.graphicalProperties.line.solidFill = "000000" # line color

s2 = mainchart.series[1]
s2.graphicalProperties.line.solidFill = "000000" 
s2.graphicalProperties.line.dashStyle = "dash"

mainchart.dataLabels = DataLabelList()

mainchart.dataLabels.showVal = False
mainchart.dataLabels.dLblPos = 't' 
mainchart.height = 15 
mainchart.width = 39 

#Create the Chart
chart2 = BarChart()
chart2.type = "col"
chart2.style = 10  # simple bar
chart2.y_axis.axId = 0

dataone = Reference(WorkSheetOne, min_col=2, min_row=CombBarLineDataOffsetFromTop+1, max_row=CombBarLineDataOffsetFromTop+1, max_col=13 )
doneseries = Series(dataone, title="Series Title")
chart2.append(doneseries)


cats = Reference(WorkSheetOne, min_col=2, min_row=CombBarLineDataOffsetFromTop, max_row=CombBarLineDataOffsetFromTop, max_col=13)
chart2.set_categories(cats)

# Set the series for the chart data
series3Total = chart2.series[0]
fill3Total =  PatternFillProperties(prst="pct5")
fill3Total.foreground = ColorChoice(srgbClr='996633') # brown
fill3Total.background = ColorChoice(srgbClr='996633')
series3Total.graphicalProperties.pattFill = fill3Total

chart2.dataLabels = DataLabelList()
chart2.dataLabels.showVal = False 
chart2.shape = 2 

mainchart.y_axis.crosses = "max"
mainchart.y_axis.tickLblPos = "none" # nextTo -- this doesn't work

mainchart += chart2

WorkSheetOne.add_chart(mainchart, 'A1')
```

How can I translate the difference in the XML to an attribute with openpyxl?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is with some of default values for some attributes which use 3-valued logic at times so that `None` != `"none"`, ie. `<c:tickLblPos /> != <c:tickLblPos val="none"/>` because the default is "nextTo". This plays havoc with the Python semantics (3-valued logic is always wrong) where the default is not to set an attribute if the value is `None` in Python. This really only affects ChartML and I've added some logic to the descriptors for the relevant objects so that "none" will be written where required.

But this code isn't publicly available yet. Get in touch with my by e-mail if you'd like a preview.